# Creating new H2 server programmatically

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

In H2 there are two ways to create a new in-memory database.  In the first, you explicitly create the database with a CREATE DATABASE.. SQL statement.  In the other, if you attempt to connect to a non-existent database, H2 will simply create it.  I've elected the first way because if I don't get some kind of error back how will I know to create the single table (with only two columns).

The problem is that H2 doesn't like he SQL I'm using and flags an error.  This SQL statement:

```
String sql = "CREATE DATABASE Tickets, " + USER + ", " + PASS;
```

throws this exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE DATABASE[*] TICKETS, USERNAME, PASSWORD "; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
```

Any idea about what going on in the above?   Or, can you tell me how I can tell that the DB was auto-created so that I can proceed to create the table?

Comment: Can you show me an example of the first? (Sorry stupid question I know, but I've never seen it mentioned)

Comment: You can tell H2 to throw an error if the database does not exist when connecting: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists And of course you get an error for `create database`. Check the manual: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html there is no such statement. Where in the H2 manual did you find that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you're correct when you suggest that you can create a H2 database via SQL - I think that's your basic issue...

Just connect to your DB (and it's the jdbc URL that defines the database involved) and if you don't get an exception, carry on and use it. (Create your table, etc.)